# Serving specific nested file or generic nested file if none specified

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a simple CDN that I want to be smart enough to serve a specific version of a file if the user requests it, otherwise serve them the version I give them if no version if specified.

The files I want to serve are jQuery and jQuery UI script files. The issue I'm having is I want /ui to be inside the /jquery folder, which is causing a 404 because it's being interpreted as a jQuery version.

How does overriding work in .htaccess? If all else fails I might just move /ui to the root and rename it to /jqueryui or something.

My current .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteRule ^jquery/ui/(.*)$ scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.$1.min.js
RewriteRule ^jquery/ui$ jquery/ui/2.0

RewriteRule ^jquery/(.*)$ scripts/jquery/jquery.$1.min.js
RewriteRule ^jquery$ jquery/1.0
```

http://mysite.com/jquery serves 1.0

http://mysite.com/jquery/1.0 serves 1.0

http://mysite.com/jquery/ui serves 2.0

http://mysite.com/jquery/ui/2.0 returns 404 for /scripts/jquery/jquery.ui/2.0/ui.min.js

**Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?**

(version numbers have been changed to make it more obvious what's going on)

Comment: `http://mysite.com/jquery/ui/2.0` should redirect to `scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.2.0.min.js` not `/scripts/jquery/jquery.ui/2.0/ui.min.js` - is this just a typo in the question?

Comment: That's what it __should__ do. If it does already, why would I post this question?

Comment: Does `scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.2.0.min.js` exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your regex more specific to match version numbers, then the `^jquery/(.*)$` won't match `jquery/ui/2.0`. You probably also want to be using the `L` flags so that it stops rewriting in the current iteration. Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^jquery/ui/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$ scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.$1.min.js [L]
RewriteRule ^jquery/ui$ jquery/ui/2.0 [L]

RewriteRule ^jquery/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$ scripts/jquery/jquery.$1.min.js [L]
RewriteRule ^jquery$ jquery/1.0 [L]
```

Comment: It's funny because I actually use this technique elsewhere in the same file, yet failed to think of applying it in this instance! Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly.